# The problem of double for loop with data change in python

Tags: python, database, numpy, for-loop, data-analysis

I have 100 input data line, and as you can see I try to change the value of the input data by using the 'for loop'. Consequently, my model calculates 100*6 times. Also, I want to see the minimum value of each time step(data line) and get the minimum 'dat' value index (totally I want to see the 100 number of minimum dat value).

```
realdata_file = open("C:/","r")
realdata_list = realdata_file.readlines()
realdata_file.close()
dat = [12,13,14,15,16,17]

for record in realdata_list:
    all_values = record.split(',')
    inputs_list = (numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]))
    get_list = []
    get_min = []
    get_mindat = []
    for h in dat:
        inputs_list[1] = h
        output = (n.query(inputs_list)
        output = output.tolist()
        get_list.extend(output[0])
        get_min = min(get_list)
        get_mindat = get_list.index(min(get_list))
        print(get_list)



output = (n.query(inputs_list) means that return numpy array by using input_list
```

However, when I run my code, I got these results from get_list. These are part of my results.

```
[0.384307]
[0.384307, 0.384488]
[0.384307, 0.384488, 0.385094]
[0.384307, 0.384488, 0.385094, 0.385982]
[0.384307, 0.384488, 0.385094, 0.385982, 0.387043]
[0.384307, 0.384488, 0.385094, 0.385982, 0.387043, 0.388196]
```

How can I only get the last line? I mean includes six data :(

Comment: There are missing closing parenthesis, I don't think this code actually runs (one is in the line `output = (n.query(inputs_list)`, the other is in the last line)

Comment: Obviously `C:/` is not a valid file, either.

Comment: That last line isn't valid Python. Was that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: n.query(inputs_list) <= this one I import my own code. sorry for interrupting.

Comment: sorry, I delete my directory. The whole directory is "realdata_file= open("C:/Users/Byeong Mo Seo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/ANNYB/ARC test6.csv", 'r')"

Comment: As you said, the last line is not a python language. It just my explanation of n.query(input_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unindent the `print(get_list)` so it runs after the loop instead of at the end of each loop.

Comment: When I move the line(print(get_list), it works well. Thank you :)